# How to properly freeze calzones

Tags: baking, storage-method, freezing, dough

In an attempt to streamline my weeknights I plan on baking several mini calzones and freezing them for later. How would I go about this without ruining the crust? Should I bake them before I freeze them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never had a problem freezing pastries and other dough dishes (inc. pot pies) in foil and saran wrap, however the trick is in reheating. If you are willing to give them another 3-6 mins at ~450 degrees F you should have a nice crispy crust (especially if you have an oven stone and flip the calzone* half way through).

*Assuming you make flat calzones rather than rolls, either way it's good stuff

Comment: Actually I was just rethinking this and you might have equally good luck not pre-baking them. Unless you are set on using a microwave or taster oven, the difference of baking. Not counting prep, it would be minimal; whether you bake for ~5 or ~15 minutes, it probably takes longer to preheat the oven.

Comment: Generally I do plan on baking them, but in the case that I bring one to work (and microwave it for lunch), would I have to bake them in advance for any length of time?

Comment: @dorrene In that case I would probably bake some and not bake some; bring the baked batch to work, let thaw in the fridge overnight and morning, and microwave. (*Taster oven=toaster oven)

Comment: Yeah, that sounds pretty simple. I wasn't sure if I only had to bake them halfway first or bake them all the way. Thanks!

Comment: Also, my computer at work is not letting me mark this as answered, I'll try again when I get home.

Comment: @dorrene baking them halfway will only save a marginal amount of time and the dough will be a bit too dense compared to letting the dough fully bake all at once. It might be a decent idea if you want them for work and have access to a toaster oven though.